# When go to login page, redirect to index if already login

Tags: php

When user go to index without login first, it will redirect to login page.

But how to make the system redirect the users to index if they trying to open login page when they already logged in?

its my login php:

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST["button_login"]))           //FUNGSI LOGIN
{ 

    $user   = $_POST["name"];
    $pass   = $_POST["password"];

    $sql_login      = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pass'";
    $result_login   = $conn->query($sql_login);
    $row_login      = $result_login->fetch_assoc();
    $numrow_login   = $result_login->num_rows;

    if($numrow_login==1)
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
        header('Location:index.php?');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Seems you have an approach... Does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start by testing if they are already logged in. Its also best to `session_start()` at the top of a script file

```
<?php
session_start();

// If user already logged in, send them to index
if ( ! empty( $_SESSION['user'] ) ) {
    header('Location:index.php?');
    exit;
}

if(isset($_POST["button_login"]))           //FUNGSI LOGIN
{ 

    $user   = $_POST["name"];
    $pass   = $_POST["password"];

    $sql_login      = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pass'";
    $result_login   = $conn->query($sql_login);
    $row_login      = $result_login->fetch_assoc();
    $numrow_login   = $result_login->num_rows;

    if($numrow_login==1)
    {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
        header('Location:index.php?');
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you have two scenarios:

1) If user is not logged in and visits `index.php`, he should be redirected to `login.php`.

-- You have already implemented this check.

2) If user is already logged in and visits `login.php`, he should be redirected to `index.php`.

Add a check in `login.php` at the very top:

This will check session is already set, redirect to `index.php`.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
  header('Location:index.php?');
}
```

Also, don't add ending `?>` tag.

If you add it, some FTP clients may add spaces there causing `header("Location:xyz.php")` not happening due to output already there on page.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this in your index:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header('Location:index.php');
}
```